# Includes function for Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of array.

```
m = [[-100,100], [-100,-100], [-100,-100], [-100,100]]
```

And I want to remove the duplicates. I tried

```
 aa = [...new Set(m)];

// and 

let chkdup = (arr, tar) => tar.every(v => arr.includes(v))`.
```

But I can't remove the duplicates.

In Python, I can easily check this `[-100,100] in m`. But I don't know the function in JS. `includes` is not working for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `new Set` doesn't work well is because in JavaScript, arrays with the same values are not equal. Try: `console.log([-100,100] == [-100,100]);` will return false. Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) if you simply wants to compare between arrays.

A workaround is to convert subarrays into strings, and use `Set` to deduplicate:

```js
const arr = [
  [-100, 100],
  [-100, -100],
  [-100, -100],
  [-100, 100]
];

const setArray = new Set(arr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)));

const result = [...setArray].map(x => JSON.parse(x));

console.log(result);
```

Using [lodash uniq](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) is a simple alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `[-100, 100] != [-100, 100]`. What you can do is convert the arrays into strings, and compare the strings instead, with `JSON.stringify`.

```
let m = [[-100,100], [-100,-100], [-100,-100], [-100,100]]
m = m.map(item => JSON.stringify(item).trim()) // Stringify everything (remove leading white space)
m = [...new Set(m)] // Convert to array getting rid of duplicates
m = m.map(item => JSON.parse(item)) // Parse it
```

Note that this is not very efficient (The interpreter has to convert into a string and parse the object again) but it is the simpliest solution. What it does is it checks if the `JSON` string of 2 Objects is equal an will not work with your own classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this thing using javascript **Set** , **map** then parse the value. For more information [Map with Set](https://javascript.info/map-set)

```js
 m = [[-100,100], [-100,-100], [-100,-100], [-100,100]];
 result = Array.from(new Set(m.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
 console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify your arrays using `.map()` with `JSON.stringify()`, and enter that into a set. Since you now have an array of strings, the set will remove the duplicates as it can check for equality correctly. You can then use `Array.from` with a mapping function of `JSON.parse` to convert it back into an array of arrays:

```js
const m = [[-100,100], [-100,-100], [-100,-100], [-100,100]];
const res = Array.from(new Set(m.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
console.log(res);
```